# Overwrite initial filename

Tags: vba, excel

With a little bit of help in places, I have written the below code which works perfectly but I need to be able to overwrite the initial file name (the one which we are asked to select with GetOpenFilename) to include !DNU! so users know after they have selected it, not to select the same file again especially as the files they will use are all fairly similar. You can see I tried with the line underneath 'Rename original text file but it doesn't do anything! Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

```
 Sub BACSConversion()

 Dim MyNewBook As String
 Dim MySaveFile As String
 Dim fileToOpen As Variant
 Dim fileName As String
 Dim sheetName As String
 Dim rCopy As Range

 'Turn off display alerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 'Turn off screen updates
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Ensures that the file open directory is always the same
   ChDir "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\"

 'Opens the folder to location to select txt file
  fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
    If fileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    End If
 'Creates the file name based on txt file name
  fileName = Mid(fileToOpen, InStrRev(fileToOpen, "\") + 1)
 'Creates the sheet name based on the active txt file
  sheetName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)

 'Rename the original text file
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
 Limited" & sheetName & "!DNU!" & ".txt")

 'Save active file as...
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
 Limited\BACS File Original\" & _
   fileName & ".CSV"), FileFormat:=xlCSV


 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
  Set rCopy = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

 'Open the original document where the BACS file is located
  Workbooks.Open "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information 
 (Analysis)\Phil Hanmore - Analysis\bacs conversation calc.xlsx"
 'Selects the worksheet called "Original"
  Sheets("Original").Range("A:A").ClearContents

 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
 rCopy.Copy
 Sheets("Original").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
  Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select

 'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
 Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy

  'Add a new workbook
   Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
   MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
  'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
   Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

  'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
   MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".Txt"
  'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

  'Close the new saved file
   ActiveWorkbook.Close

 'Selects appropriate worksheet - MyPayFINAL
   Sheets("MyPay FINAL").Select

  'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
   Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Copy

  'Add a new workbook
   Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

  'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
   MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
  'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" 
  & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "MyPayFINAL" & ".Txt"
 'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows

 'Close the new saved file
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
 'Close original source workbook (template)
  Workbooks("bacs conversation calc").Close
 'Close final workbook
  ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

  MsgBox "Your file has been processed successfully!", vbExclamation

 'Turn on display alerts
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 'Turn on screen updates
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub

  Sub FileNameChange()

  Dim oldPath As String
  Dim newPath As String

  oldPath = "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil 
  Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & Test & ".xlsx"
  newPath = "S:\Accounts (New)\Management Information (Analysis)\Phil 
  Hanmore - Analysis\Neil Test\" & Test & "!DNU!.xlsx"



  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built-in function in VBA called `Name`, it works as follows:

```
Name [old/current path/name] [new path/name]
```

So for your code, you would want to do:

```
Name ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & Filename) ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & Filename & "!DNU!")
```

I would recommend assigning variables to the paths, call them oldpath and newpath. So

```
Dim oldPath As String, newPath as String

oldPath = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & sheetname & ".txt"
newPath = "S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment Limited\" & sheetname & "!DNU!.txt"

Name oldPath newPath
```

BUT, the file needs to be closed before you can do this.  So make sure the file is closed by looping through the open workbooks and closing them all.  Then by running this, it should rename the file from the old name to the new name.

I would recommend making a new workbook and placing it on your desktop and testing first before using it with your real code/workbooks.  Make a new workbook, save it to your desktop, call it test.xlsx and then close it.  In a separate workbook start a new Sub and paste the code in, but change the oldPath and newPath to reflect your desktop path and test.xlsx file.  Give this a shot.

Comment: @Mat's Mug  I must doing something wrong here guys as that method did not work for me at all. I am wondering, as I have manged to create another copy of the file with DNU in the name, is just to delete the original leaving the copy with DNU in it. Is that sensible? What would be the best way to work it into my code? and for some reason I get .txt actually in the file name and sheet name, can you see what I need to remove? I tried taking part of this line out fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt") but it didn't work either!

Comment: @Dyhouse learn to use the debugger. Use F9 to set/clear breakpoints, F8 to step-through, Shift+F8 to step-over, and you can drag the yellow line to any executable instruction in the scope you're breaking in. Use the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and the *locals* toolwindows to examine variables' values and how they change when you assign them.

Comment: @Dyhouse are you receiving an error? Or is it just outright not working.  Can you edit your original post and show the full code that you are trying with Name?

Comment: @Busse I have updated my original post. Please let me know where I am going wrong. I really appreciate the help. I am fairly new to the VBA world so I am learning all the time.

Comment: @Dyhouse, I don't actually see the function `Name` written anywhere in the code.  I see you declared your variables and set them, but now you need to write `Name oldPath newPath` underneath the assignment of the variables. Did you not have this or did you just forget to add it when you updated your original post?

Comment: @Busse when I try and add 'Name oldPath newPath' I get a compile error

Comment: Your oldPath and newPath variables call a variable called "Test".  I don't see declaration or assignment of that variable.

Comment: @Busse with a bit playing around, I have actually managed to get this to work. Thank you again for your help.